# pkcs#11 capable Smart Card and Reader

Tags: smartcard, pkcs#11, smartcard-reader

Does anyone have a suggestion about which smart cards and USB readers are affordable, suitable for a VPN and for which there is PKCS#11 supoprt?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe reading the [FAQ](http://www.opensc-project.org/opensc/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions) on OpenSC project website helps to clarify the relation between cards, readers and PKCS#11

Answer (score 0):

Smart card vendors usually provides a `PKCS#11` libraries. Many cards are supported by open-source libraries such as `OpenSC`.

Reader requirements are library-dependent. Usually it is `PCSC-compatible` reader.